# Using non-numerical identifier in Rails find function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In many Rails examples I see

`ModelName.find(:id)` being used, supposed every model has a unique string attribute named `:symbol`, how can I set up the model so that `find(:symbol)` would work? Do I have to implement the searching algo myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
 ModelName.find_by_symbol("uniquestring")
```

More info on [Rails Dynamic Finders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try "find_by_yoursymbol"

```
ModelName.find_by_yoursymbol("symbol value")
```

I just used this to check if a record exists and to create it if it isn't there.

```
Spree::MailMethod.create(:environment => "test") unless Spree::MailMethod.find_by_environment("test").present?
```

Comment: You can use `ModelName.find_or_create_by_symbol('test')`, allowing you to remove the condition.